# Generalizing system call hijacking to any kernel symbol

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module

I know how to hijack system calls in modern Linux kernels well enough to engineer simple replacements for them. The code I use to hijack a system call generally looks like:

```
static unsigned long *sys_call_table = (unsigned long*)<address of system call table>;
…
int make_rw(unsigned long address) {
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(address, &level);
    if (pte->pte &~ _PAGE_RW) {
        pte->pte |= _PAGE_RW;
    }
    return 0;
}
int make_ro(unsigned long address) {
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(address, &level);
    pte->pte = pte->pte &~ _PAGE_RW;
    return 0;
}
…
asmlinkage long (*real_<system call name>)(<system call arguments>);

asmlinkage long hijacked_<system call name>(<hijacked system call arguments>) {
    // replacement code goes here
}
…
void hack(void) {
    make_rw((unsigned long)sys_call_table);
    real_<system call name> = (void*)*(sys_call_table + __NR_<system call name>);
    *(sys_call_table + __NR_<system call name>) = (unsigned long)hijacked_<system call name>;
    make_ro((unsigned long)sys_call_table);
}
void restore(void) {
    make_rw((unsigned long)sys_call_table);
    *(sys_call_table + __NR_<system call name>) = (unsigned long)real_<system call name>;
    make_ro((unsigned long)sys_call_table);
}
```

Linux exports other functions (I think they are called "symbols") that are used internally by the kernel. One such symbol is `capable`, defined in `linux/capability.c` as:

```
bool capable(int cap)
{
    return ns_capable(&init_user_ns, cap);
}
```

My theory is that I can use the same code that I use for hijacking system calls, only without the bits like `sys_call_table` and `__NR_<system call name>`. But I suspect that this might only be the case with system calls, since hijacking them involves replacing pointers to addresses. Would this work with other symbols? If not, how can I hijack them in a fairly simple way?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: your method won't work for generic functions and you want to look at [kprobes](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt).

The long answer is below:

The reason it is so easy to hijack system calls is because you are replacing the memory address of the original system call with your own function so when a system call table is looked up your function is there instead of the original function.  System call functions are basically only called indirectly via the system call table.  If some code directly called the system call function your hijack would not work.

For hijacking any function you do not have this simple method as a generic function can be called various ways.  For example, you can't simply just scan all the text and replace all call instructions with calls to your function as the function address might be stored in data (think C function pointer).

The typical way this is done is to replace the beginning of function you wish to hijack with a call to your function.  If you do not care about every returning to the original function this isn't too difficult, you are basically placing a trampoline so whenever the intended function is called the first thing and only thing the intended function does is call your function.  If you want to return to the intended function, i.e. you want to have a function that is called every time some target function is called and then go back to the target function, things are a little more difficult.  This is because you replaced some machine code at the beginning of the function that you now need.  This can be handled by generating some machine code that does what the replaced machine code does and then jumps to the rest of the original function code.  This is basically what [kprobes](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt) is doing except kprobes puts the debug instruction (int 3 for x86) at the beginning of the function and then the debug handler calls the probe function as opposed to placing a call to your instruction.

Note this is a somewhat high level explanation as the details are architecture specific.  For example, when you replace the intended instructions if the instructions are instruction pointer relative instructions things get complicated as the instruction pointer is not what it would typically be.  I would suggest looking at [kprobes](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt) for some of the architecture specific details.

Answer (score -1):

Linux kernel symbol addresses can be found at /proc/kallsyms. You should be root if you access that part because many kernels employ a security check not to expose kernel symbols to unprivileged users. The reason is it helps a lot in building an attack vector.

These symbols are different from the system call table and are stored entirely in kernel space, so you can't access those memory addresses like you did with the syscall tables. If you try - you will find that accessing the memory address you want to change will crash your program.

If you want to change `capable` (or, to go deeper, `ns_capable`), you need to be able to write to the kernel address space and override the binary code in `ns_capabale` address you found from kallsyms. There are no function pointers you can hijack, just actual binary.

I assume you own the machine you're trying this on, so switch to root and `cat /proc/kallsyms | grep ns_capable` (may or may not work as non-privileged too, depending on the kernel). Now you have the address of the beginning of the function you want to hack.

If you are at a friends house and don't have access to a privileged account, you can still employ the guidelines below to find a weakness for kallsyms and change it's behavior to export symbols to anyone.

Now you have to find a security failure in the kernel (a weakness) and exploit it so that you could write into kernel space and replace the instructions for `ns_capable` with `mov eax, 1` and `ret` which means return true.

This is actually the challenging part. Here you will have to find a weakness that the target kernel is vulnerable to in web sites like [this](http://www.cvedetails.com/product/47/Linux-Linux-Kernel.html?vendor_id=33) or [this](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-33/product_id-47/cvssscoremin-7/cvssscoremax-7.99/Linux-Linux-Kernel.html) or [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CVE) or [this](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=linux%20kernel) (you get the point - it's public knowledge (; ) and develop an exploit to do what you need.

Browsing through the list of CVEs is tiresome, and many weaknesses will not help you gain write access to the kernel space, but be patient, read the summaries through and find a weakness to exploit.

I'm not profound of system call internals, but if you run your code from userspace, that means the address you're changing is within the process running it. Didn't see anything other than straight access and as far as I know, you can't access memory addresses outside your process memory space because it will fault.